# How can I prevent PrimeNG Tree onNodeSelect() from firing when using templating?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, primeng

I am attempting to use a PrimeNG Tree with templating.  Everything is displaying fine, but any click inside my template is selecting/deselecting the node, is there anyway to prevent this?  In the following code I only want a click on the  element to call doSomething(), not nodeSelected() as well:

```
<p-tree [value]="tree" selectionMode="checkbox" [(selection)]="treeSelected" (onNodeSelect)="nodeSelected($event.node.data)">
    <ng-template let-node pTemplate="template1">
        {{node.label}}
        <span class="labelDescription">Type 1</span>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" (click)="doSomething(node.data)">Do Something</a>
    </ng-template>
</p-tree>
```

Comment: Put (click)="null" to try on the p-tree tag

Comment: @Vega - Well I still want nodeSelected() to be called when the checkbox or label is clicked, just not when the <a> element is clicked.

Comment: I understand, that's why asked to try :) did it work to 'block' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Angular's [event binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#event-binding-event) and add this inside `doSomething`() method. It will intercept the event bubbling from the item to the row by simply preventing it:

```
doSomething(event, item){      
   event.stopPropagation();
   // as before you had
}
```

and change the HTML to:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" (click)="doSomething($event, node.data)">Do Something</a>
```

Comment: I added this event.stopPropagation() to doSomething(), not nodeSelected(), and it worked.  Many thanks.

Comment: I mixed the bubbling and capturing. I guess you can also use stopImmediatePropagation(). Glad I could help.

Comment: Nice with passing the $event.node as a parameter. If printed to the console I see that parent is undefined? Instead of stop propagation, is it possible to get parent?

Comment: How do you print to console? with which statement?